# Number of lattice points in a circle

Tags: python

I am trying to determine the number of lattice points in a Circle i.e. Basically I am trying to find the number of pairs (m,n) such that m^2+n^2 <= r^2, where m and n are both integers. I used the code below to do this, but I get the wrong answer for r = 12, which is supposed to be 441 according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) and I get 121 and I was wondering where I might be wrong:

```
def latticepoints(N):
    num = 0
    for m in range(0, int(N), 1):
        for n in range(0, int(N), 1):
            if (m**2 + n**2) <= N**2:
                num = num + 1

    return number

print(latticepoints(12))
```

**Edit**:

Just solved it. Just needed to change the loops to:

```
for m in range(-int(N), int(N)+1, 1):
    for n in range(-int(N), int(N)+1, 1):
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you've already noted, the problem is that you're counting lattice points in a single quadrant of the circle. Expanding the range to fix this is one approach; an alternative fix is to take

```
lattice points = 4 * (lattice points in a single quadrant) - 3
```

We have to subtract 3 because the first term counts the origin four times.

---

Since you've already found the bug, here are a few quick comments on other ways to improve your code:

- `range()` can take up to three arguments: start, end and step:

  - If supplied with only two arguments, it defaults step to 1
  - If supplied with just one argument, it defaults start to 0 and step to 1

  In general, you should supply as few arguments as you can get away with (letting the defaults do the rest) – this cuts down on visual noise.

  So in the original function, you'd write

  ```
  for m in range(int(N)):
  ```

  and in the fixed version, you'd write:

  ```
  for m in range(-int(N), int(N)):
  ```
- Since your example supplies N as an integer, I'm not sure why you're continuously casting to int(). It would be better to do a single cast to int() at the start of the function, and then remove the rest of the casts. That will cut down on visual noise.
- The function as supplied throws a NameError. It's counting lattice points in the variable `num`, but returns `number`, which hasn't been defined yet. Quick fix is to tidy up the return statement; better would be to use a more descriptive variable name such as `lattice_count`.

  Note also that you can replace `num = num + 1` by `num += 1`.
- If `m > sqrt(N)` or `n > sqrt(N)`, clearly the lattice point (m, n) will fall outside the circle of radius N. As such, you could speed up your loops by only looking at `-sqrt(N) <= m <= sqrt(N)`, and likewise for `n`.